# Will Microsoft UI Automation be ported to Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: accessibility, windows-10-mobile, uiaccessibility, windows-10-universal, accessibilityservice

We are looking to develop Accessibility Apps for windows 10 mobile, but have noticed a distinct lack of hooks to be able to trigger help for users requiring Accessibility enhancements.

Something like UI Automation for desktop windows, that can run in a background service and improve the experience for people with disabilities - over and above the offerings within the OS.

Are there any plans to port UI Automation to mobile? If not, is there an equivalent?

Comment: I believe your question has been downvoted because you're asking the wrong people and in the wrong place. You should have come up with a specific programming issue seeking help from people that could give you a clear answer.

Comment: I checked, there wasn't a SO forum for windows mobile, this is the most likely forum to get answers from the community - even msdn search indexes this site.

Comment: I agree this question is probably better asked in a Windows forum, but I was wondering about the same thing. So upvote!